# Is there a way to include inline js and css code directly from .js and .css files in twig?

Tags: javascript, css, symfony, twig, symfony-3.4

I'm working on a huge website with a lot of sections and landing pages, and we're calling all the css and js from files (which are cached in our CDN), but now we want to test inlining all the css and javascript code needed in landing pages to check if that improves our site speed.
So instead of calling the files itself, is there a way to render the files inline in twig?

Edit: The css/js files are minified and we are using the best approach considering cache and our CDN... but in this case, the landing pages where we want to test it, the user is not supposed to navigate to any other page - that's why we want to inline everything and check if that improves some of the site speed metrics for those pages in particular.

Thanks

Comment: I think you're not asking the right question. If your js/css are correctly cached by the browser, you shouldn't get speed issue regarding of retrieving the js/css except on the first page load. Hardcoding the js/css directly will not be in the cache and will be on each requests.

Comment: Instead of writing the js/css inline, may suggest you minify it? https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/frontend/assetic/uglifyjs.html

Comment: all the js/css are minified already... we just want to check if the site speed improves in the landing pages as we don't expect the user to navigate to other pages, that's why we want to test inlining everything instead.

Comment: I don't know twig very well but does this could work? `<script>{% include 'app.js' %}</script>`

Comment: One thing I usually do is to bundle my JS when I have heavy parts that aren't required everywhere. Example in a project I worked on: I had 3 folders: `admin/`, `client/` and `common/`. Another one I had graphs and calendar; I did a dedicated JS file for each since it was loaded on a single page and were adding extra 50~100kb.

Comment: Thanks @ClémentBaconnier, but one more time, that's exactly what I do... I just use the css and js that is needed for each page. What I'm asking here has nothing to do with that. I just want to know if there is a way to include the css/js code from their files inlining them directly to the html code with <script> and <style>.

Comment: With the information you provided, I have no idea what you did with your files and what JS you have. If you're trying to find speed optimization for some landing pages while you have a "huge website", it's legit to me think that you have unnecessary JS/CSS in that pages. That the reason I'm trying to provide actual help than "micro" optimization. That being said, did  the `include` statement I suggested works?